# What is the driver name and url for mysql database for type2

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to write a jdbc program to connect with mysql using type2 driver.I spent lot of time 
  to get the url and driver name for mysql.Please dont say go to google i tried a lot in 
  google.I did not find any where.I am able to find for Oracle but not for mysql.Please help 
  me.Thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)?

Comment: @Iswanto San  i mean urlmeans not this in jdbc prorgam how i need to write

Comment: You didn't find your info at http://sourceforge.net/projects/java2mysql/files/?source=navbar? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from [a long (2002) dead project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java2mysql/) there is no Type 2 JDBC driver for MySQL.

Comment: but the link provided by you is showing jar file for type2 driver.

Comment: @PSR Read my answer again: yes I link to a type 2 driver for MySQL, but it hasn't been updated since 2002 so that project is very dead. It is old, and doesn't support newer JDBC specifications.